# React Native + ARKit = "React/RCTConvert.h not found"

Tags: ios, react-native, arkit

I am trying to use React Native with ARKit for the first time and I ran into a problem.

What I did:

```
(in Terminal)

react-native init myApp
cd myApp
npm install --save react-native-arkit
react-native link react-native-arkit

(in XCode)
Open myApp workspace under myApp/ios
Assign my Team
Trying to Build on a device
```

What I got:

```
React/RCTConvert.h' file not found
```

in color-grabber.m

I found a lot of references to the same problem online (dating back to 2017+), none of the fixes they offered seemed to work for me.

Truly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to provide an update if anyone is interested.

After a long array of manual updates to the settings I managed to fix most of the issues. However, given that the package is not supported, I gave up on it.

The way to go seems [Viro React](https://github.com/ViroCommunity/viro) which is now open source and is pretty actively supported. Unfortunately, it is not suitable for my purposes (I need a very small footprint), so I will try using iOS native components instead.